# Dynamic adding row in datatable make searchbox and row uneditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, django-templates

I am using this patch to dynamically add row in datatable. After the row is added it makes row and searchbox uneditable. Hence I'm not able to search and perform editing on the table. This is my javascript and HTML code.

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([
count++,
order['wabn'],
picker_name,
order['client'],
])
```

This is my javascript which runs if a request is successful. It runs and adds the row in table. But then search box becomes uneditable. Before this table is editable, but once the row is added dynamically it is uneditable.

```
Here is my html code. In this I am adding my table in my template.
<table id="example" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width: 10px">#</th>
<th>AWB</th>
<th>Reciever</th>
<th>client</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I have tried with make editable method but it did not work. Is there any way?

Comment: 1. Where is your search box? 2. Please provide all your HTML, including search box, and any jQuery/javascript used to edit the table. Press Ctrl+M and paste your code into appropriate locations, then check the checkbox at bottom that says *Hide snippet by default *

Comment: @gibberish search box comes when value is entered it is feature of datatable.And it is uneditable when it comes.